# Process Pandas DataFrames which don't fit in memory

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pca, hdf

I'm manipulating a huge DataFrame stored using [HDFStore](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-hdf5) objects, the table is too big to be completely loaded in memory so I have to extract the data chunck by chunk, which is fine for a lot of tasks.

Here comes my problem, I would like to apply a PCA on the table which requires the whole DataFrame to be loaded but I don't have enough memory to do that.

The [PCA function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) takes a numpy array or a pandas DataFrame as input, is there another way to apply a PCA that would directly use an object stored on disk?

Thank you a lot in advance,

ClydeX

Comment: You could just evaluate a sample of your data using PCA first, trying to do this on such a huge amount of data seems impractical at this stage because you are essentially performing feature evaluation

Comment: If I use a sample the output will be less accurate but it will of course be an option if I can't manage to analyze the whole table.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a perfect fit for the new [IncrementalPCA](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html) in the 0.16 dev branch of scikit-learn.

**Update**: [link to the latest stable version](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html)

Comment: Indeed, I will try partial_fit(X) with the different chunks of my table.

Thank you!